# How to dynamically change a CSS class based on apex attributes

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <div class="container">
            <template for:each={Opportunitys.data} for:item="Opportunity">
                <a key={Opportunity.Name} class ="red/orange or green">
                    <div>{Opportunity.Name}</div><br>
                    <div>{Opportunity.StageName}({Opportunity.Probability})</div><br>
                    <div>{Opportunity.CloseDate}</div>
                </a>
            </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS :

```
import { api, LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import selectOpportunities from '@salesforce/apex/ApexOpportunities.selectOpportunities';

export default class LastOpportunity extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @wire(selectOpportunities)
    Opportunitys;
}
```

Apex :

```
@auraenabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Opportunity> selectOpportunities(){
        return [
            SELECT Name,StageName, Probability, CloseDate
            FROM Opportunity
            WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
            ORDER BY CloseDate
            LIMIT 5
            ];
    }
```

CSS :

```
body{
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.red{
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.orange{
  background-color: orangered;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.green{
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

i want to change the class name according to the data Opportunity.Probability
exemple :
if Opportunity.Probability < 60% CSS class = red
if Opportunity.Probability = 100% CSS class = green

do you have any solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

you can add a class attribute to your data, so, in your iteration, you can assign classes dynamically.

lets say that you data returns something like:

```
[{id: 'someid', name: 'some name' stage: 'some stage'}]
```

you could do something similar to this:

```
this.someProperty = yourData.map( record => {
return {
        ...record,
        css: (record.stage === 'something') ? 'orange' : 'green'
       }
    }
```

and replace your data attribute in your iteration:

```
<template for:each={someProperty} for:item="Opportunity">

    <a key={someProperty.id} class={Opportunity.css}>
...
```